# Date input only one integer not day,month and year in C

Tags: c, date, int

I want to write a C program that counts the years of a car by entering the Registration date. I can only use one int instead of day, month and year as integers. How can I count with only the year if the whole date is the int?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int inputDateOfFirstUse, ageCalculation, age;

        printf("\nProgram to calculate the age of a car");
        printf("\nPlease enter the date of the first use (in this syntax tt.mm.jjjj): ");
        scanf("%i", &inputDateOfFirstUse);
        ageCalculation = inputDateOfFirstUse - 2018;
        age = ageCalculation;
        printf("\nThe car is %i years old.", age);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even within C language, using English words for identifiers helps most people here to help you.

Comment: Would you please translate the text into English for better understanding? I honestly don't know what the variables are.

Comment: If you really have an input like "13.1.2018" most of the information will not make it into your `int`variable. Change to fgets() to read the whole line into a "string", then work on that for parsing day, month and year.

Comment: You ask people to input in the form `tt.mm.jjjj` but the dots prevent such a number being interpreted as an integer (unless perhaps you're using a locale where `.` is used as a "thousands separator" and `,` is the decimal point).  You should really ask people to enter `ttmmjjjj` (or, as the English-only die-hards would have it: `ddmmyyyy`).  To extract the year from such an integer, you'd need to use `int jjjj = eingabeZulassungsdatum % 10000`.

Comment: Why not use strings for the date entered? Then fetch the appropriate substrings and do the conversion?

Comment: I used a rough translation for "Erstzulassing", should be good enough for the programming question here.

Comment: Not related to the described problem, but I expected `2018 -
 inputDateOfFirstUse`.

Comment: It is common to use a single int for a date, because it allows easy comparisons. But it is weird to only use the year. You should Google for *Julian date* for an exemple of such a representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `scanf` you can use the `%*i` syntax to skip the values you don't care of.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        int inputDateOfFirstUse, ageCalculation, age;

        printf("\nProgram to calculate the age of a car");
        printf("\nPlease enter the date of the first use (in this syntax tt.mm.jjjj): ");
        scanf("%*i.%*i.%i", &inputDateOfFirstUse); // Skips day and month, reads only year
        ageCalculation = 2018 - inputDateOfFirstUse;
        age = ageCalculation;
        printf("\nThe car is %i years old.", age);
        return 0;
}
```